# Looping with Sentinel Values (C#)

Tags: c#, while-loop, average, sentinel

I'm sure that this is fairly simple but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to enter valid credit scores from 300 to 850 with -99 as a sentinel value and calculate the average based upon that. I might be missing something really simple (most likely)... Please help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreditScores
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int creditScore;
        int totalScore = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int average;
        string user;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter credit score; press -99 to exit");
        user = Console.ReadLine();
        creditScore = Convert.ToInt32(user);
        count = ++count;
        totalScore += creditScore;

        while (creditScore != -99)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter credit score; press -99 to exit");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            creditScore = Convert.ToInt32(user);
            count = ++count;
            totalScore += creditScore;

            while (creditScore < 300 || creditScore > 850)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid score; please enter a valid credit score");
                user = Console.ReadLine();
                creditScore = Convert.ToInt32(user);
                count = ++count;
                totalScore += creditScore;
            }
        }
                average = totalScore / count;
                Console.WriteLine("The average of all {0} scores is {1}", count, average);             

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If I enter -99, it always comes back as "Invalid score; please enter a valid credit score" and never displays the average.

Comment: Does that happen even if it's the first number you enter?

Comment: If it's the first number that I enter it will say, "The average of all 1 scores is -99".

Comment: Try running the code [step by step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) to see where you get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you clarified that this only happen if `-99` is not the first number the user entered I'm just going to narrow in on the `while` loop that is causing the issue.

When the user enters -99, `creditScore` is less than 300 so it prints the 'Invalid Score' message.

Following along the execution (notice my added comments).

```
while (creditScore != -99)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter credit score; press -99 to exit");

    user = Console.ReadLine(); //User enteres '-99' here

    creditScore = Convert.ToInt32(user); //creditScore is evaluated to -99

    count = ++count;
    totalScore += creditScore;

    //This is what's causing the problem. 
    //This is now: while (-99 < 300 || -99 > 850)
    //Notice that -99 < 300 is true, and therefore the while loop is executed
    while (creditScore < 300 || creditScore > 850)
    {
        //Execution reaches here when creditScore = -99
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid score; please enter a valid credit score");
        user = Console.ReadLine();
        creditScore = Convert.ToInt32(user);
        count = ++count;
        totalScore += creditScore;
    }
}
```

To fix this, you need to add a separate conditional to check if creditScore is -99 and deal with that.

This seems like it may be a homework question, so I'm going to leave that as an excersise for you, but if not let me know and I'll can edit in a solution :)